# Buffer log out interrupted by alert box

Tags: buffer

Every time I try to log out of Buffer (the free version) I get an alert box with the message: "There are still requests processing in the background, everything might not be saved!"

As far as I can tell the application had responded to all the requests I have made. Is their a reason for this message?